# How to sum based on field value (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I got this table named `tb_stock`

```
ID AMOUNT FLAG LAST_AMOUNT
1   5     N    0                
2   0     Y    8                
3   0     Y    7                
4   6     N    0
```

Right now i want to sum the value based on the FLAG value. For example if the FLAG values is N, it will sum from the AMOUNT field and if the FLAG value is Y, it will sum from the LAST_AMOUNT field.

So the total amount would be 26 (5 + 8 + 7 + 6).

Is this can be achieve with just use mysql or it will involve php as well?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you'd have to write a stored procedure using a cursor to accomplish it purely with mysql.  You could create a simpler solution with a different database structure (add a field `AMOUNT_TO_SUM`, set to either `AMOUNT` or `LAST_AMOUNT` and do a sum of that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN FLAG = 'Y' THEN LAST_AMOUNT ELSE AMOUNT END) AS TOTAL
FROM tb_stock
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an example using `IF` statement

```
SELECT SUM(IF(`flag`='y', last_amount, amount))
FROM example_table
```